# Is there any reason to have a firewall located on a public ip address?

Tags: firewall

Usually you want it on a private IP address for security reasons.

Is there a plus side to having your firewall on a public IP?

I don't think there is, but I wanted to cover all my bases.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would argue that you need a firewall on the public IP address and you may not need on on the private addresses. Personally I have instance firewalls on everything and only open up the ports required on the public and private addresses.